# Diff and intersection reporting between two text files

Tags: python, list, shell, compare

**Disclaimer: I am new to programming and scripting in general so please excuse the lack of technical terms**

So i have two text file data sets that contain names listed:

```
First File | Second File
bob        | bob
mark       | mark
larry      | bruce
tom        | tom
```

I would like to run a script (pref python) that outputs the intersection lines in one text file and the different lines in another text file, ex:

*matches.txt*:

```
bob 
mark 
tom
```

*differences.txt*:

```
bruce
```

How would I accomplish this with Python? Or with a Unix command line, if it's easy enough?

Comment: use `sets` and standard file io ... with a `string.split` in there for good measure :)  ... or what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Is the Unix `diff` command not good enough?

Comment: I suspect the ordering doesnt matter so probably not ...

Comment: please note these are listed vertically ( if it matters)

Comment: Yes,ordering doesn't matter. I am more comfortable with unix but thought it would be a good exercise in learning how i can accomplish this with python. I am an absolute beginner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
words1 = set(open("some1.txt").read().split())
words2 = set(open("some2.txt").read().split())

duplicates  = words1.intersection(words2)
uniques = words1.difference(words2).union(words2.difference(words1))

print "Duplicates(%d):%s"%(len(duplicates),duplicates)
print "\nUniques(%d):%s"%(len(uniques),uniques)
```

something like that at least

Comment: hey i had a question, if the file is too big will the entire content be stored in the set, is there any efficient way to do it for large files?

Answer (score 16):

sort | uniq is good, but comm might be even better.  "man comm" for more information.

From the manual page:

```
EXAMPLES
       comm -12 file1 file2
              Print only lines present in both file1 and file2.

       comm -3 file1 file2
              Print lines in file1 not in file2, and vice versa.
```

You can also use the Python set type, but comm is easier.

Comment: Note that `comm` needs sorted files as input.

Comment: Here's an old tool I wrote that does a variety of set operations in Python. It does not require sorted files, and it's intended to be called from a shell: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/set-arithmetic/

Answer (score 11):

Unix shell solution-:

```
# duplicate lines
sort text1.txt text2.txt | uniq -d

# unique lines
sort text1.txt text2.txt | uniq -u
```

Comment: Note to the OP: to output to a file, just redirect the output with `> file.txt` at the end of the command, like this: `sort text1.txt text2.txt | uniq -d > dups.txt`

Comment: via [clfu], for duplicates (http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5707/intersection-between-two-files#comment) : `(sort -u file1; sort -u file2) | sort | uniq -d` (this seems to do the same though and is shorter)

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionaries are O(1) or very close, in other words they are very fast (but they use lots of memory if the files you're indexing are large). So first read in the first file and build a dictionary something like:

```
left = [x.strip() for x in open('left.txt').readlines()]
```

The list comprehension and strip() is required because readlines hands you the lines with the trailing newline intact. This creates a list of all items in the file, assuming one per line (use .split if they are all on one line).

Now build a dict:

```
ldi = dict.fromkeys(left)
```

This builds a dictionary with the items in the list as keys. This also deals with duplicates. Now iterate through the second file and check if the key is in the dict:

```
matches = open('matches.txt', 'w')
uniq = open('uniq.txt', 'w')
for l in open('right.txt').readlines():
    if l.strip() in ldi:
        # write to matches
        matches.write(l)
    else:
        # write to uniq
        uniq.write(l)
matches.close()
uniq.close()
```

Comment: Come to think of it, this won' find the unique names in left.txt. Simple enough to just mirror the dict solution to get that, but you can also look at the python "set" type, which allows you do easily determine the intersection/difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> with open('first.txt') as f1, open('second.txt') as f2:
        w1 = set(f1)
        w2 = set(f2)


>>> with open('matches.txt','w') as fout1, open('differences.txt','w') as fout2:
        fout1.writelines(w1 & w2)
        fout2.writelines(w2 - w1)


>>> with open('matches.txt') as f:
        print f.read()


bob
mark
tom
>>> with open('differences.txt') as f:
        print f.read()


bruce
```

Answer (score 0):

Made one with horizontal lines;

---

```
file_1_list = []

with open(input('Enter the first file name: ')) as file:
    file_1 = file.read() 

    file.seek(0) 

    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        file_1_list.append(line)

 with open(input('Enter the second file name: ')) as file:
    file_2 = file.read()
    file.seek(0)
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()

if file_1 == file_2:
    print("Yes")

else:
        print("No")
        print(file_1)
        print("--------------")
        print(file_2)
```