# Is there a way to crawl a webpage in python where the crawler shoud fetch only the new links.

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to crawl a webpage(news) and get only the latest links. 
I have a crawler code which gets all the links from a website and takes like 2-3 hours to get around 30000 links and stores in db.
What if next time when I run the crawler I want only the new links to be inserted.
I know I can do a filter before inserting in db, but I would want the crawler to fetch only new links other than crawling the old links again(basically entire website). 
Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: Is there a way on the website to distinguish "old links" against "new links"? If not, then I'm afraid there is no miracle solution besides looping through all the links and inserting only the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of a cache.

One solution which comes to my mind is storing a local version of the website. When you want to add the new links you can make a diff between the new version and your locally stored version. Afterwards you can crawl over the diff...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any particular way to do things you suggested? like have you tried it before or do you know any links where I can find it.

Comment: I am not experienced with python and I never wrote a diff function on my own, to be honest. However I found the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289458/diff-and-intersection-reporting-between-two-text-files And I know that for example Notepad++ has a Plugin which can be used to compare two text files... I think it's gonna be quite complex to develop a robust diff-functionality completely on your own

Answer (score 0):

This is actually something that would be best handled in the DB. Put a unique key constraint on the column that holds the link, when you go to insert, the DB will reject the write and let you continue on your merry way.

Your SQL would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `links` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` VARCHAR(1023) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url_unique` (`url`)
);
```

Comment: I want to reduce the time it takes to crawl and not insert. I understand your method but it does not serve the purpose here. Thank you for the reply.